# SimpleDeform problem

Tags: modifiers

When i bend on `Z` axis, all ok.

[image]

But, when bend on `Y` axis...

[image]

Something wrong... why?

Comment: maybe try 2 different things: apply its rotation, rotate it 90° on the Z axis?

Comment: Yep. thanks....